# Solid-state lasers: The peak power of each pulse is at least three orders of magnitude above the average output power?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, laser, photonics

My textbook, *Solid-State Laser Engineering*, 6th edition, by Walter Koechner, says the following:

> *Average Output Power*. The majority of solid-state lasers available commercially have output powers below 20 W. The systems are continuously pumped, typically equipped with a Q-switch, and often combined with a wavelength converter. Continuously pumped, repetitively Q-switched lasers generate a continuous stream of short pulses at repetition rates between 5 and 100 kHz depending on the material. Since the peak power of each pulse is at least three orders of magnitude above the average power, breakdown of reflective surfaces and subsequent material removal by melting and vaporization is facilitated.

I find this section confusing. How does it make sense that the peak power of each pulse is at least three orders of magnitude above the *average* output power? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the pulses are very brief.  When the laser is operating, it is dark more than 99.9% of the time, and all the power is generated in the sub-0.1% of the time that there's an active pulse.

Imagine a neighborhood where there are 999 broke people and one millionaire. The "mean" inhabitant has a thousand dollars, but that's not a good description of any individual.

Comment: Ohh, I see where my confusion was. The units of power are Watts, which are in turn joules per *second*. So "power" includes a time dimension.